# How to enter event registrations after event has ended

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration, price-sets

We are using Civi 5.0.1 on Wordpress 4.9

We had our conference two weeks ago.  Most of the attendees signed up online through the website.
We also allow attendees to Walk in and signup and pay during the event.
Today I was asked to enter the information for the people who walked in and paid during the conference.
When I try to save their information for the event registration I get the error you see in the screenshot. 
I believe this is due to the event having ended.  How can I add registrations and have them associated with an event that already ended?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you set end dates not just on the event, but on the price fields as well.  If so, you can remove the end dates from the price fields and that should fix your issue.

Public registration will still be impossible.  End dates on price fields are only necessary if that price option goes away before the event takes place (e.g. early bird pricing).